# Create an array that is dynamically sized?

Tags: c#, arrays

My hangman program is functioning correctly, although I'm trying to create a section of code that performs a simple task.

I wish to create a module whereby when the user inputs a word (string) it will allocate this word to an array, and this process can be repeated until they feel they have created enough words and exit out of this section into the game itself. I have tried some part of this code but i'm really struggling with the string array and how it can dynamically increase in size based on how many words the user is inputting.

**How do you create an array that adds in new string's each time the user presses enter until they have created as many words as they wish?**

```
static string UserQuestions()
{
   Console.WriteLine("Please input your words, press 1 when you have finished");
   string UserInput = new string[Console.ReadLine()[0]];

   for (int i = 0; i < UserInput; i++)
   {
   }

   if (UserQuestionsExit == 1) ;
   {
      break;
   }
   return UserInput;
}
```

---

**My second question is I'm having trouble linking the new list through to a random generator that will randomly select one of these words from the list and return it as a string to be used in my hangman game?**

```
static char UservsUserRandom(string userQuestion)
{ 
    Random rnd = new Random();
    int response = rnd.Next(0,userQuestion.Length );
    char randWord ;
    {
        randWord = userQuestion[response];
    }
    return randWord;
}

var userQuestion = UserQuestions();
value = UservsUserRandom(userQuestion);
char[] newValue = new char[value.Length];
```

Comment: Try using an alternate data structure, such as an ArrayList or generic List.

Comment: Arrays aren't dynamically sized, try using a list or arraylist instead.

Comment: @Zach - Great minds, my friend...

Comment: forget arrays. use a `List<string>`

Comment: yer thank you, i haven't learnt a great deal on lists at the moment as i'm only in my first year but i will take on your advice and try this. Thank you again

Answer (score 5):

Array sizes are fixed in .NET, so if you don't know how many items you may need to read in, it's probably not a good option. Use a [`List<string>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead:

```
var userInput = new List<string>();
while(true)
{
    var lastInput = Console.ReadLine();
    if (lastInput.Length > 0)
    {
        userInput.Add(lastInput);
    }
    else
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

Lists are actually backed by arrays, but they allow you to efficiently add and remove elements dynamically. When necessary, it will automatically resize the internal array to accommodate more items.

---

Regarding your update, to pick a random string from this list you can use a method like this:

```
private static Random rnd = new Random();

static string GetRandomString(List<string> inputStrings)
{ 
    int response = rnd.Next(0, inputStrings.Length);
    string randWord = inputStrings[response];
    return randWord;
}
```

Note that I've moved the `Random` outside of the method in question. This will be useful if you need to call this method multiple times in a short period of time. You can then use this method like this:

```
var userQuestion = UserQuestions();
string selectedString = GetRandomString(userQuestion);
...
```

Also, if you need to convert the `string` to a `char`, the simplest method is to use [`ToCharArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ezftk57x%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
char[] charArray = selectedString.ToCharArray();
```

Comment: I'm having real trouble implementing this list into the rest of my code, that section has worked fine but i'm having trouble firstly naming that method now its a list, and secondly how i can send this list up to a random generator to randomly select a word. Could anyone help on this>?

Comment: Make sure you have `using System.Collections.Generic` at the top of your file. To pass the list around within your program, just make return type or parameter type `List<string>` instead of `string`.

Comment: i dont mean to take up a lot of your time, but if i commented my work to give you an indication of how its working do you think you could try and pick up where ive gone wrong and how i should do it? im not looking for someone to do this for me, i just want to learn how to do it.

Comment: @user3084866 Sure you can edit your question to provide more information (but do not change the question in a way that invalidates the other answers), and I'll see if I can help you.

Comment: ok i edited it, sorry for the state that its in but if you need any more info im happy to help

Comment: @user3084866 Your code right now takes a single string, and returns a random single character from it. You want it to take a list of strings, and in the same way, return a string from it. You can index into lists (returning an item from the list) in the same way you're indexing into the string (returning a character from the string.) You just need to change the type of object you're passing in (list of string rather than string), and the return type (string). (Also, future reference, it's probably better to post a new question, if the two questions are as unrelated as these two are.)

Comment: @user3084866 Please see my updated answer. And *neminem* is correct; I directed you to post the update because I thought you were having trouble implementing this solution in your code, I didn't realize you were working on a separate method. The second question really should have been posted separately.

Comment: i apologise and thank you both for your patience. This has really helped my understanding and im very grateful for you explaining why and how this was done. next time i will be careful about posting a new question

Answer (score 1):

How you do it is you don't use an array, you use a List - which is like an array, except that it's designed to have in it an arbitrary number of items.

```
List<string> items = new List<string>();
string userInput = Console.ReadLine();
while (userInput != "1")
{
    items.Add(userInput);
    userInput = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried a List? Arrays can't really expand dynamically, and basically shouldn't.
have a list :

```
 List<string> words = new List<string>();
  words.Add("new word");
```

when user presses 1 , you can simply words.ToArray() to make it an array, or continue using it as list. Hope it helps!